# Hacer que devuelva cero cuando no hay resultados

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, subconsultas

Tengo un SP de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ING_COMPxPRODUCTO 
@Fecha_Ini date,
@Fecha_Fin date
AS
SELECT A.Id_Producto, B.Pro_Descripcion, C.Mar_Descripcion, D.Um_Descripcion,
A.Cantidad, A.Pu_Compra, A.Total, F.Alm_Descripcion, G.Tde_Descripcion, E.Ep_NroDocumento, E.Ep_Fecha,
@Fecha_Ini AS FECHA_INI, @Fecha_Fin AS FECHA_FIN FROM TB_DET_ENTRADA_PRODUCTOS A
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUCTOS B ON A.Id_Producto = B.Id_Producto
INNER JOIN TB_MARCAS C ON B.Id_Marca = C.Id_Marca
INNER JOIN TB_UNIDADMEDIDA D ON B.Id_Unimedida = D.Id_Unimedida
INNER JOIN TB_ENC_ENTRADA_PRODUCTOS E ON A.Id_Ep = E.Id_Ep
INNER JOIN TB_ALMACENES F ON E.Id_Almacen = F.Id_Almacen
INNER JOIN TB_TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_EMITIR G ON E.Id_Tde = G.Id_Tde
WHERE E.Ep_Estado = 1 AND E.Ep_Fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_Ini AND @Fecha_Fin
ORDER BY Pro_Descripcion
GO
```

y al ingresar una fecha cuyo resultado no tenga registro me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que salga 0

Apoyarme porfavor

Comment: Por qué no insertas los resultados en una tabla temporal, luego a la tabla temporal le haces un `count(*)` y luego retornas el resulset si el conteo es mayor que cero, o `0` en caso contrario. Por cierto, es una mala idea y una terrible decisión de diseño. No debería haber ningún problema en retornar un resulset vacío. Tu back-end sólo tiene que contar las filas para tomar una decisión.

Comment: Eso lo manejas en las vistas, sino hay resultados pones un aviso que no hay nada y listo...

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres que salga 0? Tienes campos no numéricos, como la descripción del producto, y las fechas, ¿en estos también quieres que salga 0?

Comment: Solucionar eso en SQL Server requiere leer dos veces los datos. Es mejor poner la validación al momento de llamar la consulta.